# coefficients of a power series

Tags: power-series

I have the function $$f(x)=\frac{2x}{10+x}$$ and I am asked to find its power series representation which I found to be 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} *\frac{2x^{n+1}}{10^{n+1}}$$ and I found the radius of convergence to be $R=10$. All until here is clear and easy, but when I am asked to find the 1st few terms I tries to do the following

- $c_0$ I plugged a value of $x=0$ in my **original** function $f(x)$ which equals $(0)$  **[correct answer]**
- $c_1$ I plugged a value of $x=0$ in the **1st** derivative of $f(x)$ which equals $\frac{1}{5}$  **[correct answer]**
- $c_2$ I plugged a value of $x=0$ in the **2nd** derivative of $f(x)$  **[incorrect answer]**
- $c_3$ I plugged a value of $x=0$ in the **3rd** derivative of $f(x)$  **[incorrect answer]**
- $c_4$ I plugged a value of $x=0$ in the **4th** derivative of $f(x)$  **[incorrect answer]**

So if $c_0$ and $c_1$ are correct why would the others not be as well? Am I missing something profoundly important?

Comment: You're forgetting the factor of $\frac1{n!}$ in the coefficients. This doesn't matter for $c_0$ and $c_1$ since $0! = 1! =1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{2x}{10+x}=\dfrac{2x}{10\left(1+\dfrac x{10}\right)}=\dfrac x5\left(1+\dfrac x{10}\right)^{-1}$$

For $\left|\dfrac x{10}\right|<1,$
$$\left(1+\dfrac x{10}\right)^{-1}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(-\dfrac x{10}\right)^r$$